# Error printing from Chrome: "The selected printer is not available or not installed correctly. Check your printer or try selecting another printer."

Tags: google-chrome, printing, printer

This problem keeps recurring on a Windows 10 PC. When trying to print from Chrome, the dialog window states "The selected printer is not available or not installed correctly. Check your printer or try selecting another printer." This occurs regardless which installed printer is selected.

We have been able to resolve this issue by closing out of Chrome, deleting the /%userprofile%/AppData/Google/Chrome folder and restarting Chrome but the problem keeps happening after a few days. My question is, what is causing this problem to keep happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure. I've never seen this. Try these steps.

1. Go into control panel > Uninstall a program. Click google chrome and click uninstall.
2. Go into the applications folder (Like you've done) `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` and delete any folder that sounds like it is by google. (ex. Chromium, Google, Google chrome)
3. Go into `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\temp`, click ctrl + a and click delete. If an error pops us saying "file in use" check the option to do for all files with same error and click skip. (This step is not required, but is highly reccomended.
4. Re-Install google chrome

If these steps do not work - Try going into another web browser and printing there. This could be because of a driver that is not installed or an outdated printer driver.
Check these things! Hope you can figure out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome [had](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=946665) a bug that it keep in it's own printer list old printers even if in the OS the list is not the same. It's stated it's now fixed, but to state the workaround;

You can read here; [Issue 946665: [FR] Add policy to prevent Chrome from displaying recent printer destinations](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=946665)

The workaround was to set the that setting to 1 (Enabled);

> Registry Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
> Registry Path:
> Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
>  Value Name:
> PrintPreviewUseSystemDefaultPrinter
>  Value Type: REG_DWORD
>  Enabled
> Value: 1 (Disabled Value: 0)

That settings force Chrome to refresh it's printer's list.